# Comparison in if statement is not working as expected in bash with test command

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am a rank newbie who is trying to get my very first "if then" statement to work. I concocted a total bs situation to use as a trial but it does not work. I have read about a half doz descriptions about how to format an if then but I get no clue about what I might be doing wrong.

my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ 10 > $1 ]
then
    printf "Too big\n"
else
    printf "Too small\n"
fi
```

I figured I could provide any number as the first parameter at the command line and the script would tell me an appropriate answer. No joy. All I ever get at the cmd line is:

```
Johns-iMac:~ johnyoung$ ./test3 5
Too big
Johns-iMac:~ johnyoung$ ./test3 50
Too big
```

For the practice I have been doing this script ended up being called  "test3"

Any body able to help me out? Thanks loads.

Comment: Have a look at [7.1. Introduction to if](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) in Bash Guide for Beginners.

Answer (score 3):

The `>` in `if [ 10 > $1 ]` is interpreted as output redirection in the test command `[`. You can use bash built-in `[[` `]]` to to numerical comparison.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ 10 > $1 ]]
    then
    printf "Too big\n"
    else
    printf "Too small\n"
fi
```

You can also use `-gt` (greater than), `-lt`(less than), `-ge`(greater than or equal to) etc numerical comparisons:

```
if [[ 10 -gt $1 ]] 
...
...
fi
```

or

```
if (( 10 > $1 ))
...
...
fi
```

In general, builtin keyword `[[` `]]` should be preferred in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) as it doesn't do glob expansion or word splitting and less error prone to use when compared to the test command `[`.

But the downside is that `[[` `]]` is not supported by all shells while the test command `[` is supported by all all shells out there.

Also read: [What is the difference between test, [ and [[ ?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) for a detailed discussion.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, `>` is not the operator "greater than". Use `-gt` instead.
Also, your if statment needs to end with `fi` and not `if`.

`>` in bash is used to redirect outputs for programs. E.g. `date > date.txt` will put the output of the command "date" to a file "date.txt"

To start with bash scripting, you could take a look into this tutorial:
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html#toc11

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
if [ 10 -gt $a ]
...
```

to compare numbers